# Swift - How do I save inputed information in UITextfield via time interval?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, viewcontroller

How do I save inputed information in multiple uitextfields? and when I switch between viewcontrollers how does the inputed information stay within its uitextfields when switching back and forward? perhaps set within a time frame which then resets itself?

I want the uitextfields to be set automatically without using the "load" function to recall the information back.

Can I see an example in "view controller.swift" thanks.

I am using Xcode 7 - Swift 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are switching view controllers.

If you are popping, or any other method that destroys the view controller, you will need to store the text from your text fields somewhere else. From what you've written, it seems like you are losing the data.

You should make a class to hold your data, and reference a singleton on that class. You make a class with a singleton like so:

```
class SomeManager {
    var mySavedString: String?
    static let sharedInstance = SomeManager()
}
```

Then in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, access the information from the singleton class and fill your views with it.

```
self.myTextField.text = SomeManager.sharedInstance.mySavedString
```

You can also make the UITextField's delegate your view controller, and then update the saved string whenever the content of the UITextField changes.

```
@IBAction func textFieldDidChange() {
    SomeManager.sharedInstance.mySavedString = self.myTextField.text
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but only for first UITextfield, when I set the functions for the second UITextfield and launch the app and input data into the second UITextfield and switch forward and back between the view controllers, the inputed data that I put in the second UITextfield changes the value in the first UITextfield. How can this be done separately? ideally I want to achieve this with five UITextfields but I want them to save within their designated fields without them changing their value within the other UITextfields thanks.

Comment: Hi mate did you manage to find a solution to this? I would appreciate your help cheers man.

Comment: You should create a property like `mySavedString` for each of the UITextFields in your application. If you have 5 UITextFields, you should have 5 Strings on your `SomeManager` that store the text for their respective UITextField.

Comment: I have done that and I have done that for each string but when I have inputed the data in, for example I filled all the UITextfields and when i input the data into the 5th UITextfield and continue forward to the next view controller and return back, the inputed data that was stored in the 5th UITextfield "ABSD" has re-populated itself in the other UITextfields. So in essence I have the "ABSD" string set for all five UITextfields. I have already tried your method before but its not working.

Comment: I have fixed the problem now, thank you very much for your help I appreciate it. I had to create additional   var mySavedStringA: String?
and for the second  var mySavedStringB: String? under class SomeManager {